# Javascript: Merge two objects with spread operator

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = {
  1: {
    687: {
      name:'test1'
    }
  }
}
var b = {
  1: {
    689: {
      name:'test2'
    }
  }
}
var c = {
  ...a,
  ...b
}
console.log(c)
```

I was expecting the result to be :

```js
{
  1: {
    687: {
      name:'test1'
    },
    689: {
      name:'test2'
    }
  }
}
```

But, it is :

```js
{
  1: {
    689: {
      name:'test2'
    }
  }
}
```

Am I using spread operator wrong? What is the most efficient way to merge two objects? I made a function which iterates through each key in the objects, it works but I think it's not the write way.

`Object.assign({},a,b)` also returns the same (first result, which I don't want).

I went through the question [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

But It doesn't answer my question. this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/1352853) is also not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: even if spread would work, it would overwriting the object with the last object.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's fine. that's actually what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/2008111 might not answer the question but solve the problem :)

Comment: Nope, the spread operator applies a shallow merge. So it's merging two objects with a single field '1', yielding an object with just one field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: You need to merge the *sub* objects: `var c = {
      1: {
        ...a.1,
        ...b.1
      }
    };`

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah! I need to, but how?

Comment: google for "object javascript deep merge".

Comment: @Ataomega um, I wrote it in that comment.

Comment: @JaredSmith upvoted though `a.1` is invalid, should be `a[1]` or in full     `var c = {
      1: {
        ...a[1],
        ...b[1]
        }
    }` (only chrome 60+ and FF55+ support too.)

Comment: @Kaiido true, my error. I don't normally try to use non-strings as property keys :P. As for the browser coverage, OP used spread so I figured it was game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lodash merge actually does what I exactly need.

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/03/30/combining-settings-objects-with-lodash-assign-or-merge

```js
// Defined within your component
var defaultSettings = {
    strictMode: true,
    formatting: {
        finalNewline: true,
        quotes: "double"
    }
};

// Provided by the developer using your component
var userSettings = {
    formatting: {
        quotes: "single"
    }
};

var assignedSettings = _.assign({}, defaultSettings, userSettings);

// {
//     strictMode: true,
//     formatting: {
//         quotes: "single"
//     }
// }

var mergedSettings = _.merge({}, defaultSettings, userSettings);

// {
//     strictMode: true,
//     formatting: {
//         finalNewline: true,
//         quotes: "single"
//     }
// }
```

Comment: While handy, this should not be the accepted solution. It asks for a javascript solution and not a lodash utility, so either go with Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2) or the object spread operator I'd say.

Comment: it's cool to know about lodash merge method, nothing wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator is for arrays and iterable objects.
If `x = ['A','B','C'];`
Then `...x` is equals to writing `x[0], x[1], x[2]`.

You want to merge the nested objects key by key from each object, not replace the previous values.

```
let key;
let c = {};
for (key in a) {
    c[key] = Object.assign({}, a[key]);
}
for (key in b) {
    c[key] = Object.assign(c[key] || {}, b[key]);
}
```

Comment: How deep would it go?

Comment: This one will go only 1 level deep. For deeper levels, a recursive function is needed

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals

Comment: @AtaMohammadi Pretty deep! xd